# Possible to bind "Switch to Fullscreen Space" to key combo?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

I have several "permanent" Spaces in use and bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>

I'm running `iTerm2` in full screen mode and would like to find a way jump straight to the iTerm "Space" with a key combo (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>). Is this possible?

I know I can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> / <kbd>Left</kbd> Arrow to navigate spaces, including the fullscreen "space". I'm looking for a way to jump to it with a single key combo.

Answer (score 0):

In Automator you can build a service. Choose no input in every application. Then add the step Run applescript and paste this script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    activate application "iTerm2"
    return input
end run
```

Save the service. Now you can assign a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences...Keyboard...Keyboard Shortcuts...Services...General. Choose a shortcut that has not been assigned, like `⌃⌥⌘9`

I've tested it with Safari not with iTerm2 but it should work with every application.

Comment: This solution almost works but:   

- It only seems to correctly jump to the fullscreen terminal if I'm in Space 1. If I'm in Space 2 or 3 it just makes the "invalid input" sound.  

- If I have multiple iTerm windows open, only one of which is fullscreen, it selects the last used iTerm window like CMD+TAB would. Which is to be expected based on the applescript but isn't quite what I need.

I've been playing with the demo for [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/); it seems to make CMD+TAB saner with fullscreen. May be the best I can do.